# How to validate and update the model when user types in UItextfields in swift

Tags: swift, validation, model-view-controller, uitextfield

I am creating a user profile screen which displays user details using MVC architecture.

I have UserProfileViewController where I will add the view dynamically based on whether user is in edit mode or normal mode.

When user is in normal mode -  I load the normalView(Which I designed with separate xib) with labels to display the user details from the model.
When user in edit mode - I load the editView (Which I designed with separate xib) with textFields prepopulated with the value from the model.
I get the user details from the service call and update the model.

Now, when in edit view - How do I make textFieldDelagate comes to UserProfileViewController not the editView class?

And I need to validate and update the model when user end the editing of the field.
How do I do that?
Please provide if have any example or reference. I have searched but didn't get correct answer to solve my issue.

Comment: So, you have two views, one view, one edit. You want to know how to load either view based on some condition and then how to update the model when editing is "done"?  So, to begin with, you would seem to need some way to start the "editing" mode, like a navigation button, which gives you the opportunity to switch the views. Again, when the user is done editing, I'd imagine you'd have some navigation button (like "Done") which needs to be tapped, again, providing you the opportunity to process the results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `editView`, add these lines of code,

```
class EditView {

    public weak var textFieldDelegate: UITextFieldDelegate?
}
```

Then in `awakeFromNib` if `EditView` is subclass of `UIView` or in `viewDidLoad` if `ViewController`, filter all textFields and set their delegate as below,

```
yourMainView.subviews.filter({ $0 is UITextField}).forEach { view in
   (view as? UITextField)?.delegate = self.textFieldDelegate
}
```

Now in `UserProfileViewController` add this conformance,

```
extension UserProfileViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // TextField editing done
    }
}
```

finally, when you are instantiating `editView` in `UserProfileViewController`, set its `delegate` to `self` like this,

```
editView.textFieldDelegate = self
```